# Django wont start with Docker

Tags: django, docker

Docker starts my django server and says its up at 0.0.0.0:8000, but i cant reach it in my browser, neither 0.0.0.0:8000 nor 127.0.0.1:8000 work

```
web_1  | You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until 
they are applied.
web_1  | Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
web_1  | April 30, 2017 - 03:36:35
web_1  | Django version 1.8.5, using settings 'my_project.settings'
web_1  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
web_1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Dockerfile

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you map a port on your host to port 8000 on the container? For example, you can specify `--publish 1234:8000` in the `docker run` command to map host port 1234 to container port 8000, then reach it at `http://localhost:1234/`.

Comment: I am using "docker-compose up"

Comment: @MikeJohnsonJr Ok, then do you have a [ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) config specified?

Comment: Yes, "8000:8000"

Comment: Can you post your Docker Compose file? And, what are you using for a Docker environment?

Comment: Sure. And I'm not sure what you mean by your second question (I am new to Docker). I see "ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1" in my Dockerfile.

Comment: No worries! I meant are you running on Docker for Mac, Docker CE on Ubuntu, Docker on Windows 2016, etc.?

Comment: Oh, I'm on Windows 7

Comment: Ah, you're likely using the legacy [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) then? In that case, you need to find the IP of the VM that's running your Docker engine. If you run `docker-machine ls`, it should show the IP of your active engine. Then, go to port 8000 of that for your container.

Comment: King Chung Huang, running "docker-machine ls" I found that docker is running on 198.162.99.100:2376. I went to 192.168.99.100:8000 in my browser and got "This page isnt working...192.168.99.100 sent an invalid response"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the legacy Docker Toolbox then, in that case, you need to find the IP of the VM that's running your Docker engine. If you run *docker-machine ls*, it should show the IP of your active engine. Then, go to port 8000 of that for your container.
for e.g- http://192.168.99.100:8000/
Here, 192.168.99.100 is the IP address of VM that's running my Docker engine.

Also, you have to add VM's IP in your ALLOWED_HOST in setting.py file